# Onclick function do not run

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a dropdown menu when click on IMG.

This is my javascript function

```
<script language='javascript'> function menu_mov(){document.getElementById("naveg").visibility = "visible"; }
```

This is my HTML code

```
<img id="menu_movil" onclick="menu_mov()" alt="menu" src="images/iconos/menu_movil.png" />
            <h3>Telf: 944 128 112
                <br>
                C/ Padre Esteban Pernet, 1 bajo, (Esq. C/Karmelo) Bilbao  
            </h3>
         </div>
         <nav id="naveg">
            <ul>
                <li class="actual menu"><a class="boton" href="inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a class="boton" href="tratamientos.html">Tratamientos</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a class="boton" href="galeria.html">Galería</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a class="boton" href="novias.html">Novias</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a class="boton" href="indiba.html">Indiba</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a class="boton" href="beauty-party.html">Beauty Party</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a class="boton" href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li> 
            </ul>
         </nav>
```

And this is my CSS code

```
#naveg{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -80px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#menu_movil{
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    margin: -25px 0px 0px -15px;
}

.menu{
    display: block;
    border-left: 0px;
    line-height: 15px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

I try to change IMG for other, and function run, but when I want to show menu, the function do not run. Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: any errors on your browser console?

Answer (score 5):

You need to update from

```
document.getElementById("naveg").visibility = "visible";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("naveg").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Answer (score 2):

There were two problems, your script missed style and the script block was not closed properly

```
<script>
  function menu_mov(){
  document.getElementById("naveg").style.visibility = "visible"; 
  }
</script>
```